# How to translate Willow Hair in french

Tags: traduction, coiffure

I thought it would be like:

1. Cheveu Saule
2. Saule Cheveu
3. Cheveux Saule
4. Saule Cheveux
5. Cheveux Seche

What would be the correct translation of singular willow hair?
This is the name of a beauty and hair products company, which they want translated. The name is a creative analogy of the natural hair, and the waviness of a willow. It's for Beauty and hair products. Just a company name

Comment: What does that mean in English?

Comment: Can you provide us with some context? It would help us understand what it means and how to translate it. Honestly, right now, I have no clue what this is about.

Comment: Sans doute des branches de saule pleureur, wikipédia parle de "branches- lianes". Je ne suis pas sûre de comprendre quelqu'un qui me parle, hors contexte, de "banches-lianes" ... Des botanistes/jardiniers ici ?

Comment: I am having a hard time finding this expression beside the name of a hairdresser salon. [With an image search](https://www.google.lu/search?q=%22willow+hair%22+-salon+-smith&safe=off&es_sm=93&biw=1280&bih=909&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoATgKahUKEwjatLDWnpbHAhWHtxQKHX3TA5g#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=%22willow+hair%22+-salon+-smith+-hannigan+-buffy), the results do not have much in common. We really need you to describe what kind of hair is a "willow hair" to you. What I can already tell you is that the translation will be plural and I have never heard any of your proposition in France.

Comment: I think it refers to the style of haircut that is called  *coiffure volumineuse* in French (there might be a more technical word to a professional hairdresser). It implies longish wavy (but not curly) hair. @Chop: I suspect OP means *coiffure* and not *cheveu(x)*.  Outside any context  "willow hair" could also refer to the colour of the hair.... but if OP wants a precise answer he should no doubt improve his question.

Comment: @Laure Yes, I agree we are trying to describe a hairstyle, but that does not imply to use the word _coiffure_ or _coupe_. Outside professional grounds, I find it quite unnatural, actually (except maybe with cl-r's _coupe au bol_, which is quite commonly known). What comes to my mind to describe your proposition would be: "_Elle a les cheveux ondulés et mi-longs._" Describing my hairstyle would not even refer to hair: "_Il est chauve/a le crâne rasé._"

Comment: What kind of company is it? Beauty and hair products? Is it the name of a haircut or a shampoo? What are the characteristics (hair that's long, short, straight, curly, wavy, dry)?  Something else? Tree cutting company? Is this a literal willow we're talking about? If you have absolutely no context yourself, I strongly suggest you contact the company who gave you this to translate and ask them what this is about. Blind translation is always bad, blind *professional* translation is... well, worse.

Comment: Please explain what “willow hair” is. Is this a hairstyle? or some biological feature of a tree? or something else? If it's a hairstyle, what defines it? I could find some pictures [1](http://www.thesimsresource.com/artists/Xandher/downloads/details/category/sims2-sets-hair/title/willow-hair-collection/id/765134/) [2](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nami-naeko/16441377638/in/photostream/) [3](http://www.daz3d.com/willow-hair-for-genesis-2-female-s-and-victoria-4) but I don't see the difference with “wavy hair”, is there one?

Comment: @gilles it's for a company, it's just an analogy of the natural hair, and the waviness of a willow. It's creative

Comment: @Kareen Beauty and hair products. Just a company name, see what i sent to gilles.

Comment: You want something short and suggestive for a company name. I'd suggest  ***boucles et volumes***.  It is not an accurate translation but  the closest to what you want to convey.  Both words used together refer directly to hair & hairstyle, *boucles* to curls & waves, and *volume* is  the usual word when talking about pumped up hair. *Boucles et volumes* is something any French  woman would identify with  a willow hairstyle. *Saule* would not be suggestive at all, as you can realize from the above comments.

Comment: Ok, so it's a hairstyle. What's the difference between “wavy hair” and “willow hair”? Please edit your question to add the information that you've posted in comments and to clarify the meaning and the context.

Comment: @Gilles Can you give a direct translation first please?

Comment: @Gilles "willow hair" is not a set phrase in English either, it's just an image. The image can be more readily understandable in English because of the nature of the English language that can easily commute functions (e.g. noun to adjective). In French they'd need to say something like, *à la façon de* *comme*...

Comment: @laure Any suggestions? Mainly because Boucles et Volumes is a little off? Any other suggestions?

Comment: @NewBeginnings No, I can't give a direct translation, because it would be meaningless. (“Coupe en saule” would be a direct translation of the meaning — we'd call it a willow cut, not willow hair — but French people would not understand it to mean wavy hair, and I think it would be taken to be deprecative.)

Comment: A direct translation would just not be clearly understood. If you really want to keep the willow image you could go with *des cheveux look saule pleureur*, "look" being used in French to mean "style". But honestly it would not sound good for a trade name.

Comment: So Stack Exchange, if I understood well, is **not** a place for students to submit their homework. But in the other hand it's OK for *companies* to make us work for free ?! Contribute to *advertising*, of all things ? I'm a bit baffled I admit, and I downvoted the question.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Do you want to open a meta on this? Btw [the one we have one homework](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/427/82) doesn't say we don't allow it, just that it needs to be an actual SE-compliant question. The same points, I think, apply to company-provided questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question illustrates many of the difficulties of translation. You can't hope to take a phrase and transpose it directly into another language. You'd like to preserve the construction *and* the literal meaning *and* the connotations but sometimes one of these is the best you can do.

The expression “Willow Hair” in English is ambiguous. The two most obvious interpretations are a hair (as in a thin strand of material) of the willow tree, or a hairstyle that is in some way related to the willow tree (presumably a hairstyle that looks like a willow tree). Many other interpretations are possible, for example (if *Willow* is capitalized) the hair(style) of someone called Willow.

It appears that you're referring to a hairstyle. The French word for *hair* as in one strand of hair on a human's head is [*cheveu*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheveu). However, to refer to a person's hair as in the whole set of hair they have on their head, you have to use the plural: *cheveux*. For example, if you want to say that somebody has dry hair, you'd say “*il a des cheveux secs*”. You can also use a different word: [*chevelure*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chevelure). But neither of these words is commonly used for hairstyles if the style is the result of cutting the hair: instead, we say “*une coupe …*”, where [*coupe*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coupe) (a cut) is to be understood in context to refer to a *hair* cut. If the style is a result of doing something to the hair, *cheveux* is the natural term. *Cheveux* can also be used when referring to cutting, for example in “*cheveux longs*” (long hair) and “*cheveux courts*” (short hair).

Referring to a haircut in the name of a hairdresser's saloon would make sense. For beauty products, it doesn't make so much sense.

If you want to translate “haircut/hairstyle of a willow”, you can use

- “*coupe en saule*” — hair cut like a willow
- “*cheveux en saule*” — hair like a willow
- “*cheveux de saule*” — hair (like those) of a willow

All of this is not very relevant if you aren't actually trying to refer to a hairstyle and instead just combining two words to look creative.

I looked for images of a willow hairstyle and this is a representative sample of what I found (computer model by Xandher):

[image: Willow hair]

From this and other examples ([1](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nami-naeko/16441377638/in/photostream/), [2](http://www.daz3d.com/willow-hair-for-genesis-2-female-s-and-victoria-4), I don't see a difference between “willow hair” and “wavy hair”. Wavy hair, in French, would be “*cheveux [ondulés](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ondul%C3%A9)*”.

If you want to translate “willow hair” using a more precise or less mundane term than “wavy hair”, you'll run into a cultural problem. For a French person, the willow metaphor is pretty unambiguously negative. If you tell someone they have hair like a willow, they'll think you called them ugly. Hair like a willow evokes the branches of the weeping willow which are just dropping there. The fact that it's called a *weeping* willow (same literal translation in French: *saule pleureur*) doesn't help. Examples: [“get rid of the weeping willow look”](http://bellemag2.com/fr/soins-et-maquillage/cheveux/volume2/), [“avoid (…) very voluminous cuts (weeping willow effect)”](https://www.enviedeplus.com/mode-beaute/soins-cheveux/article/quelle-coupe-pour-quelles-formes).

For a brand name that's supposed to evoke beauty, don't evoke the looks of a weeping willow.

Brand names are rarely translated literally. You have two choices:

- Keep the English name untranslated (use it as a proper name — French people have *iPad* devices from *Apple*, not *iBloc* devices from *Pomme*)
- Look for a different name (possibly a different name in different countries due to different cultural connotations). (And no, I'm not going to propose a name — that requires knowing what you're selling and where, and it's something professionals charge thousands of euros for.)

Comment: Many hairdresser salons use _hair_ in their name in France (I knew many but the only to come to mind is "Atmosp'hair").